How to move around in the console using the arrow keys, c and win32
I am writing a text editor in the C programming language, and I am stuck on how to allow the user to move around in the console window using the arrow keys. Here is my code:
// EDIT LOOP
void insertMode(char *buffer, const char *filename)
{
    // Init cursor
    int cursor = strlen(buffer);
    COORD cursorPos = {0, 0};
    HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    BOOL isEditing = TRUE;
    while (isEditing)
    {
        // clear screen, display file contents and show cursor
        system("cls");
        displayBuffer(buffer, filename);

        // Show all instruction to the user
        printf("\nesc = SAVE&QUIT\n");

        // Move the cursor to the current cursorPos
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, cursorPos);

        // Capture user input
        char ch = _getch();

        // If 'ESC' key to return to normal mode
        if (ch == 27)
        {
            // Save the file contents before exiting insert mode
            if (saveFile(filename, buffer) == 0)
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("\nFile saved successfully.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nError saving file.\n");
            }
            break;
        }
        // 'Backspace' key
        else if (ch == '\b')
        {
            if (cursor > 0)
            {
                buffer[cursor - 1] = '\0';  // Remove last character
                cursor--;
            }
        }
        // 'Enter' key
        else if (ch == '\r')
        {
            if (cursor < MAX_BUFFER - 1)
            {
                // Adds newline
                buffer[cursor] = '\n';
                cursor++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Add the input character to the buffer
            if (cursor < MAX_BUFFER - 1)
            {
                buffer[cursor] = ch;
                cursor++;
                buffer[cursor] = '\0';
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried using GPT to help me move the cursor using the arrow keys, but unfortunalaty it did not work.

"I tried using GPT to help me move the cursor using the arrow keys, but unfortunalaty it did not work." Because it knows nothing about programming let alone the Windows API. It's a chat bot, it doesn't know anything, it's just good at cooking up something that they think the human will like at a glance, correct or not.

Anyways check out SetConsoleCursorPosition.

Is this for practising/experimentation only? Otherwise you are wasting time reinventing the wheel, that's what the richedit does :)

This simple arrow key demo will do exactly as you asked: you can navigate all over the ms windows console window via the arrow keys.
It is extendable: you can activate the printf() in GetKey() to discover key values for the END and HOME keys etc, and then cause the cursor to move all the way right and all the way left, etc.
There are other ways to discern ARROW and other extended keys in ms windows, but GetKey() is as dirt simple as it gets, and usually a perfect solution for a small project that needs to get up and running right now.
move_xy() is the other innovation that makes this code work in a clean and simple manner, imo.  It calls GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo() to discover the current cursor position, then modifies the current coordinates according to the inbound X and Y parameters, and then calls SetConsoleCursorPosition() to move the cursor to the new/modified coords as desired.
This code is compiled and tested in Visual Studio by me just now.
Community:  Regrettable non-portable windows code, with apologies.  But please note the OP has asked for a solution in the ms windows platform/environment.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define LEFT_ARROW        331
#define RIGHT_ARROW       333
#define UP_ARROW          328
#define DOWN_ARROW        336

HANDLE hConOut = NULL;

/*----------------------------------------------------------- 
* GetKey()
* Assigns unique key value accounting for complexities of 
* extended keys like ARROW and F-Keys.  Thanks John Wagner.
*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
int GetKey()
{
    int key = _getch();
    if(key == 0 || key == 224)
        key = 256 + _getch();
    //printf("key: %d\n", key);
    return key;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------- 
* move_xy()
* Discovers current cursor coords and moves the cursor
* from those coords depending on params x & y 
*----------------------------------------------------------*/
BOOL move_xy(int px, int py)
{
    BOOL bsuccess = FALSE;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    if(GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hConOut, &csbi))
    {
        csbi.dwCursorPosition.X += px;
        csbi.dwCursorPosition.Y += py;
        bsuccess = SetConsoleCursorPosition( hConOut, csbi.dwCursorPosition );
    }
    return bsuccess;
}


int main() 
{
    int key, done  = 0;

    hConOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if(hConOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("STDOUT not available");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("(press esc to exit)\n");
    while(!done)
    {
        key = GetKey(); 
        switch(key)
        {
            case 27: 
                printf("\nESC entered -- Exit\n");
                done = 1;
            break;

            case LEFT_ARROW:  
                move_xy(-1, 0);
            break;
            case RIGHT_ARROW:  
                move_xy(1, 0);
            break;
            case UP_ARROW:  
                move_xy(0, -1);
            break;
            case DOWN_ARROW:  
                move_xy(0, 1);
            break;

            default: 
            break;
        }
    }

    GetKey(); /* Pause for results - wait key press */
    return 0;
}

